# ReactJS - is there any recommended way to games (2D Tile Maps)

Tags: react-native

We are doing a small mobile game with react-native. But now we are not sure if react-native is a good choice for what we wanted to create.

Our game is simply just working with tiles in a not that small "map". Lets say its 1000 x 1000 Tiles so at the end 1.000.000 Tiles.

1) Our first try was to render 1 Mio.  Components - which ended bad. Even 100 x 100 is like impossible to render with react-native.

2) We ended up to add some logic which renders just tiles inside the view. But when doing any action (and new tiles get rendered) the app is laggy as hell.

3) So we made sure no Tile get ever recreated and instead we just changed props so the tile change the position instead of being recreated. This ended up also in a laggy as hell experience (even when its like 20 Tiles just changing the prop).

After these we decided that React-Native has no nice performance for what we wanted to create: A big tile map with some interactions.

4) So we were thinking of using canvas for drawing the tiles in our react-native app, but it seems that this is also not the common way. We've found some canvas packages for react-native but these are just adding a few components which are useless for our project - with these components we would also end up by rendering components like . But the goal would be to have one ref where we can use the canvas benefits.

So - if react-native is too laggy for doing stuff like this in his own way and canvas is not useable as it is in web what would be the recommended way to solve a project like this ? Or is the answer maybe that react-native is the wrong system to solve a project like this ? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, I will never recommend react-native to make a game like you are describing (with tilemap), less-UI-focused games like poker, trading cards is totally fine though.

But you are likely rendering thousands of tiles without any clipping? How about try to enable View clipping? See removeClippedSubviews here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html

If you still want to push with react-native, I suggest using plugins like this: https://github.com/ProjectSeptemberInc/gl-react-native

The purpose is to have an OpenGL ES canvas to accelerate your game rendering.

Otherwise, for 2D games, cocos2d-js seems fit to you (it seems your background is javascript), although it will requires some compiler knowledge to get the game actually running on mobile device. The other solution would be Unity 3D (2D is completely find with this engine). Each engine has their own pros/cons, so I would suggest you to try both at basic level to see which one is more suitable.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs - some are new to me and I will research them :)

Comment: I agree.  I have used gl-react.  You can follow tutorials for webGL and it works exactly the same.